# Can you turn off payments completely?

Tags: checkout, cart, magento-community

I'm setting up a Magento Community install and this site creates orders but does not take any payments. hen checking out, it should ask for customer details, but not ask for payment details or show Paypal links etc. It has nothing to do with Paypal's Bill Me Later feature. Everything is handled on the company side as far as payments and invoicing. So I would just need customer adds items to their cart, they go to checkout, it asks to login or enter their customer details, then it just creates the order.

Is this possible with configuration or do you need a separate module?

Comment: Try this: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-payment-method-step

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can!

Just use cheque/bacs - it is native to Magento, requires no modifications or extensions. You can pop a message in there outlining the steps required.

Very simple, takes seconds, wholly native.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with configuration or with any existing extensions (correct me if I'm wrong). Unless you want extend some core logics, you can consider an alternative approach, perhaps?

Alternatively, you can enable only the check/money order option for payment and change its name to "No payment necessary" or something like that in the system configuration.

Then, you can hook onto the `sales_order_place_after` event to update this order to complete, so you don't need to do anything on it manually.

This, ultimately, will have the same end results you're looking for, as far as I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom 'psuedo-checkout-page' that just clears the cart and redirects the customer to whatever 'thank you' page you'd like and accepts their data with which you can do whatever it is you'd like.